# Redraw datatable after ajax success - NOT SERVERSIDE PROCESSING

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable (NOT SERVERSIDE PROCESSING) that i have 2 links, one approve and one deny for each row.
Once either link is clicked it modifies the database. This is working fine, i also use the following to remove the row after either of the links is clicked.

```
parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300); 
parent.slideUp(300,function() {});`
```

The problem is if the approve button is clicked the days_left in the datatable is modified by a calculation (this works fine) but i need to then redraw on ajax success.

So process would be click approve link, calculates the days_left, updates the table with the new days left column.

Any help would be great Ive been stuck on this for a while.

[image]

```
$('a.deny').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).closest("tr");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: 'index.php',
      data: 'ajax=1&deny=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),
      beforeSend: function() {
        parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
      },
      success: function() {
        parent.slideUp(300,function() {});      
    }
    });
  });


$('a.approve').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).closest("tr");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: 'index.php',
      data: 'ajax=1&approve='+ parent.attr('id').replace('record-','')+'&employee='+ parent.attr('title')+'&acyear=' + parent.attr('lang'),
      beforeSend: function() {
        parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
      },
      success: function() {
        parent.slideUp(300,function() {});
        var $adwpTable = $("#department_waiting_approval_table_a").dataTable( { bRetrieve : true } );
        $adwpTable.fnDraw();                
        }
    });
  });
```

**EDIT - MORE INFO ADDED**

```
if(isset($_GET['approve']) && isset($_GET['employee']) && isset($_GET['acyear'])) {
  $result = mysql_query('UPDATE requests SET approved = 1 WHERE id = '.$_GET['approve'].'');
  $result2 = mysql_query('UPDATE holiday_entitlement_business_manual 
          SET days_left = new_entitlement- IFNULL((SELECT sum(days) 
          FROM requests where user='.$_GET['employee'].' AND academic_year='.$_GET['acyear'].' AND approved=1),0) 
          WHERE userid='.$_GET['employee'].' AND academic_year='.$_GET['acyear'].'');
}


if(isset($_GET['deny'])) {
  $result = mysql_query('UPDATE requests SET denied = 1 WHERE id = '.$_GET['deny'].'');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just provide a data parameter in the success function

```
$('a.deny').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var parent = $(this).closest("tr");
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'index.php',
  data: 'ajax=1&deny=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),
  beforeSend: function() {
    parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
  },
  success: function(data) {
    parent.slideUp(300,function() {});  
    parent.children('.days_left').html(data);
}
});
```

});

The script you call then has to return the remaining days.

Comment: Thanks for the response, although not sure what you mean. I have edited me question to include what happens after click.

Comment: Right. After the MySql query you can just return (e.g. echo) the remaining number of days, this will be passed to the success function as 'data'.

Comment: something now happens but it changes the row in which the button is clicked therefor its useless as it get removed with parent.slideUp(300,function() {}); I need to update all rows as they are the same person. Please see in my pic in question.

Comment: I meant this as an example: Beneath parent.slideUp you can choose any selector you want (e.g. the column with the specified id, class or data attribute) and have it updated.

Comment: So if i put a class on that column of class="days_left" how would i write to update all with ('.days_left').html(data);

Comment: scratch that last stupid question - $('.days_left').html(data);

Comment: For the approve column i have the link & tick img. but when the days_left = 0 i replace the link with '-'. this is so the request cant be approved when they have no days left. How can i replace the tick column in the same function?